How to get a normal function from a context function, and viceversa?
If I have a value of type I ?=> O, and I need to pass a value of I => O somewhere else, is there an idiomatic way of achieving that change?

Probably  i => f(using i) or maybe even f(using _) would work

For val f: I ?=> O = ??? use one of
val f1: I => O = i => f(using i)
val f1: I => O = implicit i => f
val f1: I => O = i => {given I = i; f}
val f1: I => O = { case given I => f }

How to test fastparse parsers in a separate class?
correct Scala 3 syntax for providing a given from a higher order function argument
Vice versa
val f: I => O = ???
val f1: I ?=> O = i ?=> f(i)

